# DataSift - python api - how do you stop a stream?

Tags: java, python, datasift-python

When I want to start listening to a stream on DataSift I use start_stream_subscriber()

But how do I stop listening to the stream?

I found no method in the API that stops a stream, and thus stopping DataSift from billing me.

Comment: Are you referring to this library? https://github.com/datasift/datasift-python

Answer (score 0):

You can register callback method that listens for stream closing with [on_closed](http://datasift.github.io/datasift-python/datasift.html?highlight=start_stream#datasift.client.Client.on_closed).

Comment: but how do I close the stream? How can I trigger the stop?

Comment: I think you cannot trigger the close. Its defined as a callback method because it is triggered by the library.

Comment: and can't you somehow say that you are not interested in receiving data anymore?

Comment: Why you would need to do that? E.g. what are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: I have a background thread which starts the stream and after 1 hour it needs to stop